# Power Shell: Save Path after file is found via foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I´m still quite new to PS, so it might be easy to answer for the veterans.
I want to grab the path of a file after a search through the drives.
Current code:

```
$Drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'

foreach($Drive in $Drives)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive.Root -include FindMe.txt -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Invoke-Item
    
}
```

The goal is to save info like BIOS info in the found file.
But how can I grab the Path of the file or the found file itself to use it as a save file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: each `fileinfo` object has a `.FullName` property that has the full path & file name in it. it also has a `.DirectoryName`. property that has the full path _without the file part_. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement that.
But I´m still quite foggy on how, to be honest.
Do I get the full loop inside a variable and then check the variable.DirectoryName?

Comment: [1] get the drive list ///// [2] iterate thru that list ///// [3] get the file list for that drive ///// [4] iterate thru that list ///// [5] get the desired info from the current file item /////  [6] save it to your preferred storage ///// [7] invoke the current file item ///// that seems to cover what you appear to want to do. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

As commenter [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) suggested, just assign the command output to a variable and use the `FullName` property of the [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) class to get the absolute file path.

```
$Drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'

$foundPath = foreach($Drive in $Drives)
{
    # Find first file named FindMe.txt 
    $found = Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive.Root -Filter FindMe.txt -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
             Select-Object -First 1 

    if( $found ) {
        # Output the full path of the found file.
        # This is implicit output which PowerShell captures in $foundPath
        $found.FullName
        break
    }
}

# Output found path to the console
$foundPath
```

**Notes:**

- I've replaced `-Include` by `-Filter` which is more efficient because it is handled by the underlying .NET filesystem API. Using `-Include` the API would return all files and the filtering would be done by PowerShell, which is slower.
- I've added `Select-Object -First 1` to stop searching when the first file named 'FindMe.txt' has been found.
- Remove `| Select-Object -First 1` to get all files named 'FindMe.txt'. In this case, `$found` will be an array when more than one files are found. Also `$found.FullName` could resolve as an array due to [member access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: Thank you both very much, and zett42 especially for the detailled explanation for silly old me. You guys helpded a lot.
Will give it a go asap.